# Question about induction with summations involved

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, factorial

I need to prove the following but I'm struggling to do so:

$$\left(r+1\right)\sum _{j=0}^n\:\frac{\left(j+r\right)!}{j!}=\frac{\left(n+r+1\right)!}{n!\:}$$

So firstly I considered the case when $n = 0$ and I got that $(r+1)!$ was on both the LHS and RHS so it was true for $n = 0$.

I assumed it was true when $n=k$ but I'm not sure what to do for the $n=k+1$ step

Comment: This is a slightly disguised form of the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity): to see that, divide through by $(r+1)!$ and rewrite the resulting fractions involving factorials as binomial coefficients. There are many proofs of the hockey stick identity both here and at the link.

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side with $n=k+1$ is
$$
(r+1)\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}\frac{(j+r)!}{j!}=
(r+1)\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(j+r)!}{j!}+(r+1)\frac{(k+1+r)!}{(k+1)!}
$$
By the induction hypothesis, you can go on with
$$
=\frac{(k+r+1)!}{k!}+(r+1)\frac{(k+1+r)!}{(k+1)!}
$$
Collect the common terms and finish up.